# Inexpensive succah roof material?

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkah

Common schach materials include: bamboo poles, other wooden poles or slats, reeds, corn stalks, bamboo mats.  Reeds and corn stalks are not always readily available.  Seeking ideas for inexpensive schach materials other than those commonly used. (URLs would be appreciated.)

Comment: Grass clippings. Your neighbor will almost certainly let you take them for free.

Comment: @Double please provide a schematic how to implement that.

Comment: @user6591 I don't have one available. I'm confident it could be done, especially if price of Schach was the only concern.

Comment: The cheapest would obviously be whatever you already own in your yard / garden. If it's feasible, think of cutting down a few branches of some tree that you have. If you own it, then, it's free. The easiest thing to use is the rollable bamboo mats. They can be expensive to buy, depending on the size and material. But, it will last you many years; it's easy to store, and it sets up in a few minutes. I think, in the long run, you recover the cost in setup time alone.

Comment: I've voted to close as "too broad". My reason is b/c of the phrasing at the end of your question, "least expensive in the short run". That's based on opinion and several factors. "short run" for schach includes a combo of the succah size, storage space, and climate among other factors. If you can provide some of this info, it would greatly narrow down the focus.

Answer (score 1):

The cRc have previously [sanctioned](https://www.scribd.com/document/241975776/Schach-Mat-Fencing) certain varieties of Home Depot bamboo fencing for use as schach. I'm not sure if they are doing so this year.

Comment: The link you provided says, "...may be used as schach only if The reeds are placed perpendicular to the schach support beams rather than parallel to the beams..."  What is the reason for this statement?

Comment: If they are placed perpendicular to the beams, then they are being supported by the beams (which are themselves kosher schach) whereas if they are placed parallel to the beams they are supported by the metal wire, which leads to the problem of ma'amid be'davar hamekabel tumah (supporting schach with something that can contract ritual impurity).