# Slat Mat Schach

Tags: halacha, sukkot, schach

I've been using loose 1x2 strip lumber for schach since time immemorial, which is sort of a pain, and I've been hankering for some *roll-on-roll-off* convenience. This year I was thinking of using [jute webbing](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jute+webbing&atb=v99-1&iax=images&ia=images) or [hemp rope](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hemp+rope&atb=v99-1&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) for stringing the slats together into a mat.

My idea is to untwist a small section of rope and slip the end of a 1x2 into the opening, doing this along the length of the rope as needed, and then again on the other end of the 1x2s to bind them at both ends.

With jute webbing I could cut short slits down the length to fit the slats.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31064/5275

Comment: @Helmanfrow Like DanF said, there’s a difference between asking a personal psak question and asking a general halachic question. Did I misinterpret your wording and you aren’t asking for personal Halacha? If so, I apologize profusely.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/inexpensive-succah-roof-material/76505#76505

Comment: I don't remember what DanF said, and I came looking for ideas, opinions, maybe even advice. But if I'm in the wrong place then please allow me to apologize.